# Adding to ListView columns not increasing column count

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, count, controls

I have created a Form using the VS 2013 designer.
I added a [Listview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control and added 13 columns via the Properties window.
I then wrote a program in C# and I am able to access all of those columns using the item.SubItems[N] construct.  Also, all of those column headers appear in the [Listview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the form.

Later I added 2 new columns.  The new columns show up in the [Listview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but throw an invalid index error when I try to access them.  Also the SubItems.Count does not reflect the increase of columns in the collection.  I also notice that, in the form.Designer.cs file, those new columns are not there.

What can I do to make sure the designer file gets updated and my new columns are added to the collection?  (note: this is not related to an 'off-by-one' error or a mistake in indexing number) Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really hard to read. Can you please format the question at least into a few paragraphs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the help section of the site [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands, your question is valid question for the site but would be better received if you provided enough code for someone to replicate the problem you are having.

Comment: You just stopped too soon.  Adding the columns is not enough enough, you also have to add the sub-items to the ListViewItems that you add to the ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that the `ListView` `Columns` do not provide you with a regular matrix or grid like a `Table` or a `DataGridView`.

Instead they are what you would call a **'Jagged Array'**, meaning, that not all rows have the same number of columns.

So while you have provided / increased the maximum number of `Columns` the `ListView` will display, each `Item` has only as many `SubItems` as you have added.

If you add `Columns` at runtime you can display and access added `SubItems`, but **only where you have actually added them** to the `Item`. Before adding the extra `SubItems` they don't exist!

This is different from, say a `DataGridView` where you can freely assign values to each `Cell`, incuding those that belong to `Columns` you have created just in the previous line of code..

This is quite similar to the two types of Arrays, [Jagged Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2s05feca.aspx) and  [Multidimensional Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)..

But to get back at your title: The actual `listView.Columns.Count` **has** increased; what has **not** is the `ListViewItem.SubItems.Count` for any of the items.

Comment: Interesting and thanks for the response.  In the code, before I access a SubItem, I usually add the item first with all the subitems explicitly included, ala: listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { sub1, sub2, etc. } )); so I would have thought that I had added all the subitems.  It seems rather random.  That is, I can't determine when it will work and when it won't.  Funny, because I thought I was asking an IDE related question rather than a coding question...but if what you're saying is true, just adding the column in the IDE should not solve the problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just another followup to TaW.  When I checked again, I realized I wasn't always initializing the full list of subitems as you suggested.  My fault of course and you were 100% correct.  Thanks very much for that excellent answer.

Comment: If you are happy with it, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)